# How can I associate my account on a Stack Exchange site with my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

I remember back in the day when ServerFault and SuperUser started up StackOverflow users could associate their StackOverflow account with newly created SuperUser / ServerFault account and get a quick 100 rep boost in order to allow them to perform simple actions (vote up etc...)

I've just created a new [gaming.stackexchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) user and I'm dismayed to find myself at 1 rep! - have I missed an obvious button or is this simply not available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using two totally different Google Gmail accounts:

`******2uk@yahoo.co.uk`

and

`j*****.m*****@gmail.com`

Can you perhaps pick one and stick with it? This is the source of your problem.

(yes, it is possible to use gmail at other mail accounts..)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your terminology correctly - Google Gmail accounts are Google Accounts that don't have Google Profiles attached, right?

Comment: Ah - When I originally created my Google openID I used a non-google email, I only then later created that gmail email.  Google appears to magically now be using my gmail address as my main open id email (without asking me!) and won't let me remove it :-(.  Re-associating both stackexchange accounts appears to have done the trick though.  Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that's weird... all Stack Exchange sites currently have **automatic account association** enabled.

What OpenID did you use when creating your new account at gaming.se? For association, **you must use the same OpenID**.

**Did you by any chance use your Google Account** to sign in (not Google Profile)? Google OpenIDs are notorious in being unique by domain - thus, association won't work automatically.

I remember that there is some fix for that... I'll update my answer when I find it.

---

**UPDATE:** Here's a description of the problem with Google OpenIDs ([from here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/)):

> Google’s OpenIDs are domain specific. The very same gmail account, if you sign up on 5 different OpenID enabled websites, will result in 5 different random hash OpenIDs being generated. While this is probably OK in the general case (though still an exceedingly rare behavior among OpenID providers), it’s incredibly aggravating for us because we like to let users map their Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Meta, and Careers accounts to each other. And cross-site user mapping is a huge PITA when there is no common per-user identifier between those 5 sites. We have a workaround in place but it is not pretty, and I think writing it drove Jarrod to drink.

Here's how automatic account association works ([from here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/)):

> 1. Match by GUID. This is something we generate and assign during account association, so it’s a perfect fingerprint.
> 2. match by OpenID URL. This works for the vast majority of OpenID providers.
> 3. match by OpenID provided email address … if you are on our trust whitelist. This works for those rare OpenID providers (currently, only Google GMail) who generate domain-specific identifiers.

---

**UPDATE #2:** Once again, I'm guessing that you're trying to log in with a Google OpenID. I just made an account on Stack Overflow with another Google Account and an account on Server Fault. They were associated automatically because of the email field that Google returns with your identity. It should be working...

Comment: Right and he is running afoul of #3, mismatching email addresses.