# Unable to associate my Stack Overflow account with my Area 51 account

Tags: support, area-51, linked-accounts

I'm trying to associate my [Area 51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/48014/justin) with all of my other accounts but whenever I try and "add an login" and add my existing Google OpenID I get the following error message:

[image: Picture of my error message]

I had similar problems associating accounts [a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61158/how-can-i-associate-my-account-on-a-stack-exchange-site-with-my-stack-overflow-a) which was down to me using multiple e-mail addresses.  I've tried to use the same e-mail address this time but I tend to use them interchangeably and so I think I may have confused it...

What do I need to do to get my accounts associated properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a temporary network error. I just looked into your accounts, and they all seem to be correctly associated now.

p.s. To clear up possible confusion: when you add a login to one account, it is automatically added to all your associated accounts as well.